# Hiding desktop section on the mobile site and show asection for mobile only

Tags: php, css, responsive-design

simply I have a video background for my template , but it's loading too slow at the mobile devices ! 
what I'm trying to do to hide the video at the mobile screens and hide the mobile slider while the viewer  from a desktop

what I got

```
   @media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
     #mobi-slider { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
   }

   @media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
     #video-slider { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
   }
```

but it doesn't make sense to the code , any suggestions to do it ?

Comment: _it doesn't make sense to the code_. What do you mean? The CSS will only hide your video, it will probably still load.

Comment: the video still on the view and the mobile slider doesn't appeared ,thanks for your replay @putvande ,I got a advice to detect with php the device I'm logging from , I will try now!